# How to prevent Travis-CI generate yarn.lock OR how to ignore Lerna publish to ignore uncommited changes in working tree

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, lerna

I have a monorepo project setup using Lerna and use Travis-CI to automatically publish canary version after after all tests passed.

The problem is, in some case Yarn generates the `yarn.lock` file during install which make Lerna complaints about uncommitted file and refuse to publish.

I search through the Lerna docs but I couldn't found a way to skip uncommitted working tree and proceed the publish.

I neither found how to setup Travis to not generate the `yarn.lock` file.

Any help will be appreciated

My Travis config file is below:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 10
before_deploy: 
  - printf "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" >> ~/.npmrc
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: yarn publish_canary
  on:
    node: stable
    branch: master
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `command.publish.ignoreChanges` in [lerna.json](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#lernajson)?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues and I figured out yarn comes with [--frozen-lockfile](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install/#toc-yarn-install-frozen-lockfile) which prevents lock file being generated and fails if update is needed (I've read that it's better alternative to `--pure-lockfile` since this one won't fail if config drifts....[reference](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7395#issuecomment-285821276)).